# How to recursively convert all JPGs into one PDF in each folder using img2pdf?

Tags: command-line, bash, pdf, windows-subsystem-for-linux, conversion

I have three levels of folders like main, sub-1 and sub-2. my main folder has lot of sub-1 folders and sub-1 has lot of sub-2 folder with JPG images inside.

I copy JPG files from sub-2 to its parent sub-1 folder FROM main folder by using this command.

```
find . -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec sh -c 'for p; do
  cp "$p" "${p%/*/*}"
done' _ {} +
```

Now I have to convert all jpgs into one pdf file inside each sub-1 folder from my MAIN folder, so there will be my all copied jpgs along with converted pdf in sub-1 (pdf name should be the folder name ex: sub-1). after convert finished I have to delete the copied jpgs only inside sub-1 folder (not original jpgs), so there will be many sub-2 folders with a single pdf file.

I am using img2pdf library to covert my images. and I tried this command below it does not do the work, I could not find any solution. Now how do I make this works?

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -type f -exec bash -c 'img2pdf *.jpg -o "${PWD##*/}".pdf' {} + \
```

Comment: Using single quotes `'` will probably not let the ${...} expand as intended. I think you need not wrap the 'imp2pdf command line' in `bash -c ' ...'`

Comment: I tried still not working

Comment: OK. I had to check the details by testing. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some tests in my Photos directory tree, and the following system with two shellscripts works for me.

**`first`:**

```
#!/bin/bash

find * -type d -exec second {} \;
echo ""
```

**`second`:**

```
#!/bin/bash

num=$(ls "$1"/*.jpg 2> /dev/null | wc -l)
if [ $num -ne 0 ]
then
 echo -n "."
 img2pdf -o "$1/${1//\//-}_${num}_pictures".pdf "$1"/*.jpg
fi
```

**Edit twice: Alternate script `second`** makes a pdf file without number of pictures and 'pictures' in the name:

```
#!/bin/bash

num=$(ls "$1"/*.jpg 2> /dev/null | wc -l)
if [ $num -ne 0 ]
then
 echo -n "."
 img2pdf -o "$1/${1##*/}".pdf "$1"/*.jpg
fi
```

- Copy and paste from the code areas into a text editor and create the files `first` and `second`
- Make them executable

  ```
  chmod +x first second
  ```
- move them to a directory in PATH. If this is only for your personal use, [create and] move them in into `~/bin`. Otherwise if other users should also use these shellscripts, move them into `/usr/local/bin`

  ```
  mkdir ~/bin
  mv first second ~/bin
  ```

  You may need to reboot to get `~/bin` into your PATH.

Now you are ready to use them. Change directory to the top or the directory tree, where you have your pictures and run `first`.

**Example** (but you have local names, not Pictures like the English),

```
cd ~/Pictures
first
```

It will write a dot to the terminal window for each subdirectory where it finds at least one picture and creates a pdf file.

The you can find the pdf files with the following command

```
find -name "*.pdf"
```

**Major edit**:

After a discussion with the original poster, I think I understood the structure of the directory tree to be processed. Copies of the files at lower levels are located in the sub-1 directories with person's names.
The files in these sub-1 directories are to be merged into pdf-files.

Example:

```
$ tree -U
.
├── adam
│   ├── mkusb-minp-2-crop.jpg
│   ├── us_keyboard_for_sudo_password.jpg
│   ├── nautilus-connect-to-server-2.jpg
│   ├── pict1
│   │   ├── mkusb-minp-2-crop.jpg
│   │   └── nautilus-connect-to-server-2.jpg
│   ├── pict2
│   │   └── us_keyboard_for_sudo_password.jpg
│   └── adam.pdf
└── betty
    ├── nautilus-connect-to-server-1.jpg
    ├── mkusb-minp-3-cropx.jpg
    ├── pict1
    │   ├── nautilus-connect-to-server-1.jpg
    │   └── calamares-mount-failed.jpg
    ├── pict2
    │   └── mkusb-minp-3-cropx.jpg
    ├── calamares-mount-failed.jpg
    └── betty.pdf

6 directories, 14 files
```

If you change working directory with `cd` to where these name-directories are located, you can use the following modified `first` shellscript.

```
#!/bin/bash

find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec second {} \;
echo ""
```

It will run the `second` shellscript only in the  name-directories and not look for what is in [upper or] lower levels of the directory tree.

The following shows how `find` finds only the name-directories

```
$ find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1
./adam
./betty
```

Comment: If you have file names with spaces, there will probably be problems. One solution can be to but the command with `img2pdf` into a small second [shellscript] file and call the shellscript in the command line with `find`. This way you can have double quotes around the files: `"*.jpg"` in the small second shellscript. An alterniative is the replace the spaces with underscores: `"filename with spaces"` --> "`filename_with_underscores"`.

Comment: I tried your script, it is creating empty pdfs in each directories with wrong names, my folder name in Arabic

Comment: It works for me with a non-English western European language. It is possible that you have a problem because of the folder names or file names. I suggest that you create a second [shellscript] file and make it work for a single directory. Then make the first [master shellscript] file with `find` that calls the second shellscript for each subdirectory containing files. Can you do that yourself or do you need help with it? (You may need help from someone using the same language.)

Comment: I am totally new to this scripts sir, I think might need help

Comment: OK @Looper, I added details how to make system with two scripts,where `first` calls `second` for each subdirectory. This works for me, and I hope that it works with Arabic too. If not you need help from someone else, who knows Arabic and/or who knows better how to manage special characters in file names.

Comment: I am running the scripts in Ubuntu by WSL2, so where do I need to move the both shell scripts here. I am confused (FYI I do not have admin privilege )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129154/discussion-between-sudodus-and-looper).

Comment: @Looper OK, I did not know exactly what you wanted. I thought it best to put something in the name, that avoids giving the same name to several files, but maybe the second edit of the second file will work for you.